# gunicorn process holding reference to logrotated files causing disk space to run out

Tags: python, gunicorn, logrotate

i am using logrotate to rotate gunicorn access / error logs.

```
{
  su root root
  missingok
  compress
  dateext
  dateformat .%Y%m%d
  notifempty
  sharedscripts
  postrotate
      # Send USR1 signal to the gunicorn master, which will cause it to reopen log files.
      # http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#logging
      /bin/kill -USR1 $(cat /var/run/xxxx/api.pid 2>/dev/null) 2> /dev/null || true
  endscript
}
```

The logs gets rotated correctly and compressed, and a new log file is created.  however gunicorn does not release the pointer to the deleted log file, and continues to write to that log file.  because of this the file space on the disk is not released and log lines are lost.

i can see the entries with lsof

```
gunicorn  22284           root    9w   REG  252,1 43263609     0 117968 /usr/cachelogic/log/gunicorn_unapi_access.log-20190410 (deleted)
```

if i restart gunicorn service, the file space is freed up and the process also writes logs to the new file.  but the old logs which were written to the deleted file are lost.

i would like to solve the logrotate issue without restarting the service.  How to ensure that logs are being written to the new log file instead of the logrotated file, and the disk space is being released.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `copytruncate` option. This is how the file system works. When the process has opened descriptor to the file and you will remove that file (for example from commandline) the descriptor will be still available in memory (via `inode`). So `copytruncate` will just copy your log file, and currently opened log file (connected with gunicor) will truncate to 0.

Comment: with `copytruncate` what would happen in case if for some reason the copy is slow (huge file size / heavy disk IO), then the intermediate log lines will be lost or will those also be copied before truncate.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, some logs can be loss. I see that gunicorn should reopen all log files via USR1 signal. Maybe try to send USR1 also to children to check the behavior? There was a bug with this behavior https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/345 Which version of gunicorn are you using?

Comment: I am using `gunicorn 19.4.5`.  i will check sending USR1 to children and see.